Restoring selection in Slate
I'm working with Slate and I've developed a notion-like command bar that appears as a popover when the user types /.
Focus is automatically taken away from the editor and into the Popover.
However, once the popover is closed I'd like to focus the editor again, possibly the last selection before the popover appeared.
So far I have:
const [lastSelection, setLastSelection] = useState<Selection>()

/**
 * Opens the command popover
 */
const setOpen = () => {
  console.log('setting last selection', editor.selection)
  setLastSelection(editor.selection)
  setOpenState(true)
}


/**
 * Restores last saved selection
 */
const restoreSelection = () => {
  console.log('restoring path to ', lastSelection)
  if (lastSelection) {
    // useRef to my editor's HTMLelement
    editor.focus()
    Transforms.select(editor, lastSelection)
  }
}


editor.selection gets logged as
{
    "anchor": {
        "path": [
            0,
            4
        ],
        "offset": 19
    },
    "focus": {
        "path": [
            0,
            4
        ],
        "offset": 19
    }
}

Which looks correct to me. However selection is being restored to the start of the Slate Node.
I get this error in my console as I do the above:
Blocked aria-hidden on a <div> element because the element that just received focus must not be hidden from assistive technology users. Avoid using aria-hidden on a focused element or its ancestor. Consider using the inert attribute instead, which will also prevent focus. For more details, see the aria-hidden section of the WAI-ARIA specification at https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-hidden. 
<div role=​"textbox" aria-multiline=​"true" data-testid=​"slate-content-editable" data-slate-editor=​"true" data-slate-node=​"value" contenteditable=​"true" zindex=​"-1" style=​"position:​ relative;​ outline:​ none;​ white-space:​ pre-wrap;​ overflow-wrap:​ break-word;​">​…​</div>​

But I doubt that's related?
